# How to do this glow effect in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, effects

I have a ListView control that has cover images, posters similar to this app:

[image]

I am trying to get the same blue glow mouseover effect.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the drop shadow and center it.

Or

You can just use the OuterGlowBitmapEffect

Comment: Thanks I am not familiar with those in WPF. Are they both WPF effects?

Comment: both are available in wpf, outerglow is not for silverlight.

Comment: Also I was reading about it and it was saying the bitmap effects are slower because they aren't hardware accelerated? Then I am gonna use the drop shadow like you said.

Comment: Nope, just doing it mouse over :O So it the mouse moves over to another listviewitem, then I want that one under the mouse to get the effect instead.

Comment: @Joan Venge: Then the performance difference will likely be negligible.